# Endless Page Reloading Issue in Blazor Server App with Individual Accounts and Blazorbootstrap library ( HttpContext Access) Net 8

Tags: blazor, .net-8.0, blazor-bootstrap

I've encountered an issue while configuring blazorbootstrap with a Blazor Server app using the most straightforward setup, following the template with individual accounts in Net8. I referred to the documentation here:
[https://docs.blazorbootstrap.com/getting-started/blazor-webapp-server-global-net-8](https://stackoverflow.com)

Problem Description:
Upon following the provided steps, the login page seems to reload endlessly. After some investigation, it appears to be related to the access to the HttpContext. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a workaround for this issue.

I'm reaching out to the community for any insights, suggestions, or potential workarounds that could help resolve this HttpContext-related problem. Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Here you can see the code :
[https://github.com/ooggmm/BlazorBootsrapBlinking](https://stackoverflow.com)

I found that removing the render mode of Routes stopped the endless blinking. However, this introduced a new problem where library components misbehave, requiring the addition of @rendermode InteractiveServer in each Razor page.

```
<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
```

I want toi be able to use the library with the Individual Accounts default template